# C# Unit Tests in API Environment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, unit-testing

I am relly new to testing in C# and I didn't find a solution so far, maybe some of you can help me.

I am programming Add-Ins for a software, that provides an API. My Add-Ins is a compiled dll that I have to move into a specific folder, so the software recognizes it and includes it. I want to test my Add-In.

The problem: The software references all dlls it needs, and my Add-In is called inside the software and has therefore access to all references. When I want to perform a unit-test, The unit tests calls functions inside my Add-In, that requires the API Environment (Example: calls classes, that requires multiple dlls from software to work), and therefore the test can't perform, because I always miss a reference. I referenced the "main" API-dll, but as already mentioned It requires more than just this dll.

Is there a way to simulate the API-Environment? Do I have to Include all dlls now? Is it necessary to mock the API?
Thanks for any kind of advice!

Sife Info: Its the .Net framework and I am using the plain unit test from visaul studio (not NUnit or XUnit)

I tried:

- Include all references (With copy local true and false).
- to add the "main" DLL as link to the project.
- to specify the runsettings behaviour
- to avoid complex classes in my unit test project, but as soon as it calls Add-In functionality the problem occurs.

All the time the result was a missing reference:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'assembly' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: What you are doing doesn't sound like a unit test, but more of an integration test. I'm not saying that to be pedantic, but because you'd maybe want to see if you can split your problem into smaller parts, that abstract all your nasty DLL issues away.

To test the DDL aspects you might be able to look into something docker related and create a non-c# test to test your whole setup.

Comment: Ok thanks! I heard from integration tests, but wasn't sure if this fits the problem here. I will look for it. Is it possible to perform some kind of method testing in the integration test, like unit-tests?

Comment: Integration tests aren't a technology. You can write integration tests with unit testing technologies (like XUnit or NUnit, or the plain one you are using). But integration tests should be slim and basically a happy-path test (in my opinion). If you simply want to test whether the addin loads, maybe write something that just moves the files in the correct folder and launches the application ? would that be possible. Your integration test shouldn't test lots of behaviour in the addin - you should test that in isolation.